# Formatar linhas com base na inicial das colunas

Tags: r

```
vendedor <- c("João","Pedro", "José")
produtoA <- c(1500,2600,3700)
produtoB <- c(3500,4600,5700)
produtoC <- c(4500,5600,6700)
DRreceita <- c(150500,260500,360500)
DRlucro <- c(22575,39075,54075)

df <- data.frame(vendedor,produtoA,produtoB,produtoC,DRreceita,DRlucro)
```

O dataset tem muitas colunas, organizadas da seguinte forma: vendedor, produto"X", DR"valores em R$".
A pergunta é como formatar as linhas com separador "." das colunas que começam com "produto"
e como formatar as linhas no formato R$ 22.575,00  das colunas que começam com "DR".

Solução esperada:

```
df$produtoA <- paste(format(df$produtoA, big.mark= "."))
df$produtoB <- paste(format(df$produtoB, big.mark= "."))
df$produtoC <- paste(format(df$produtoC, big.mark= "."))
df$DRreceita <- paste('R$', format(round(df$DRreceita, 2), big.mark= ".", decimal.mark=',', scientific=F, nsmall = 2))
df$DRlucro <- paste('R$', format(round(df$DRlucro, 2), big.mark= ".", decimal.mark=',', scientific=F, nsmall = 2))
df
```

Minhas tentativas:
Uma solução parcial para o produto poderia ser a seguinte, mas ainda está sem o filtro das colunas que começam com "produto":

```
df[,2:4] <- lapply(df[,2:4], format, big.mark= ".")
```

Ou da seguinte forma, mas só consegui para o caso dos produtos, isoladamente:

```
library(tidyverse)
produto <- df %>% 
  select(vendedor, starts_with("produto"))

produto[] <- lapply(produto[], format, big.mark= ".")
```

Comment: Porquê o voto para fechar? A pergunta é sobre um problema de programação, tem dados e tentativa de solução.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem metade do problema resolvido, basta determinar programaticamente quais as colunas de dinheiro em Reais com `grep` e aplicar o `format` da questão. Notando que o ciclo `lapply` está errado, corrigido em baixo.

A função `printFormated` não modifica a base, para isso tem que fazer

```
df2 <- printFormated(df)
```

Creio que é melhor nao modificar os dados por uma questão de apresentação.

```r
vendedor <- c("João","Pedro", "José")
produtoA <- c(1500,2600,3700)
produtoB <- c(3500,4600,5700)
produtoC <- c(4500,5600,6700)
DRreceita <- c(150500,260500,360500)
DRlucro <- c(22575,39075,54075)

df <- data.frame(vendedor,produtoA,produtoB,produtoC,DRreceita,DRlucro)

printFormated <- function(x) {
  i_dinheiro <- grep("DR", names(x))
  i_num <- which(sapply(x, is.numeric))
  i_num <- setdiff(i_num, i_dinheiro)
  x[i_num] <- lapply(x[i_num], format, big.mark= ".", decimal.mark = ",")
  x[i_dinheiro] <- lapply(x[i_dinheiro], \(y){
    y <- format(round(y, 2), big.mark= ".", decimal.mark=',', scientific = FALSE, nsmall = 2)
    paste('R$', y)
  })
  x
}
printFormated(df)
#>   vendedor produtoA produtoB produtoC     DRreceita      DRlucro
#> 1     João    1.500    3.500    4.500 R$ 150.500,00 R$ 22.575,00
#> 2    Pedro    2.600    4.600    5.600 R$ 260.500,00 R$ 39.075,00
#> 3     José    3.700    5.700    6.700 R$ 360.500,00 R$ 54.075,00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Outra maneira

Outra maneira é definir uma classe S3 especial, por exemplo a classe  `"Rodrigo"`, e programar um método `print.Rodrigo`.

```r
print.Rodrigo <- function(x, ...) {
  x <- printFormated(x)
  NextMethod()
}
as_Rodrigo <- function(x){
  class(x) <- c("Rodrigo", class(x))
  x
}

dados2 <- as_Rodrigo(df)
dados2
#>   vendedor produtoA produtoB produtoC     DRreceita      DRlucro
#> 1     João    1.500    3.500    4.500 R$ 150.500,00 R$ 22.575,00
#> 2    Pedro    2.600    4.600    5.600 R$ 260.500,00 R$ 39.075,00
#> 3     José    3.700    5.700    6.700 R$ 360.500,00 R$ 54.075,00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>